# Convert SQL Server DateTime object to BIGINT (.Net ticks)

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

I need to convert a DateTime type value to BIGINT type in .Net ticks format (number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001).

The conversion should be perform in Sql server 2008 using T-SQL query

For example:

```
DateTime value - 12/09/2011 00:00:00
```

will convert to:

```
BIGINT value - 634513824000000000
```

Comment: Where are you trying to perform the conversion? Can't you fetch the value as a .NET DateTime and then just use the Ticks property?

Comment: @Jon Skeet Sorry for missing information.. I'm trying to perform the conversion in SQL Server using T-SQL query

Comment: You have to update original question

Comment: +1, while trying to figure out an answer, I learned a few things, so thanks for asking it :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have found a CodeProject article that may assist: [Convert DateTime To .NET Ticks Using T-SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DateTimeToTicks.aspx)

I enclose the SQL function from the above article (I hope this is ok? As it requires registration.)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MonthToDays365] (@month int)
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
-- converts the given month (0-12) to the corresponding number of days into the year (by end of month)
-- this function is for non-leap years
BEGIN 
RETURN
    CASE @month
        WHEN 0 THEN 0
        WHEN 1 THEN 31
        WHEN 2 THEN 59
        WHEN 3 THEN 90
        WHEN 4 THEN 120
        WHEN 5 THEN 151
        WHEN 6 THEN 181
        WHEN 7 THEN 212
        WHEN 8 THEN 243
        WHEN 9 THEN 273
        WHEN 10 THEN 304
        WHEN 11 THEN 334
        WHEN 12 THEN 365
        ELSE 0
    END
END

GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MonthToDays366] (@month int)
RETURNS int 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
-- converts the given month (0-12) to the corresponding number of days into the year (by end of month)
-- this function is for leap years
BEGIN 
RETURN
    CASE @month
        WHEN 0 THEN 0
        WHEN 1 THEN 31
        WHEN 2 THEN 60
        WHEN 3 THEN 91
        WHEN 4 THEN 121
        WHEN 5 THEN 152
        WHEN 6 THEN 182
        WHEN 7 THEN 213
        WHEN 8 THEN 244
        WHEN 9 THEN 274
        WHEN 10 THEN 305
        WHEN 11 THEN 335
        WHEN 12 THEN 366
        ELSE 0
    END
END

GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MonthToDays] (@year int, @month int)
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
-- converts the given month (0-12) to the corresponding number of days into the year (by end of month)
-- this function is for non-leap years
BEGIN 
RETURN 
    -- determine whether the given year is a leap year
    CASE 
        WHEN (@year % 4 = 0) and ((@year % 100  != 0) or ((@year % 100 = 0) and (@year % 400 = 0))) THEN dbo.MonthToDays366(@month)
        ELSE dbo.MonthToDays365(@month)
    END
END

GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TimeToTicks] (@hour int, @minute int, @second int)  
RETURNS bigint 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
-- converts the given hour/minute/second to the corresponding ticks
BEGIN 
RETURN (((@hour * 3600) + CONVERT(bigint, @minute) * 60) + CONVERT(bigint, @second)) * 10000000
END

GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateToTicks] (@year int, @month int, @day int)
RETURNS bigint
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
-- converts the given year/month/day to the corresponding ticks
BEGIN 
RETURN CONVERT(bigint, (((((((@year - 1) * 365) + ((@year - 1) / 4)) - ((@year - 1) / 100)) + ((@year - 1) / 400)) + dbo.MonthToDays(@year, @month - 1)) + @day) - 1) * 864000000000;
END

GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateTimeToTicks] (@d datetime)
RETURNS bigint
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
-- converts the given datetime to .NET-compatible ticks
-- see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx
BEGIN 
RETURN 
    dbo.DateToTicks(DATEPART(yyyy, @d), DATEPART(mm, @d), DATEPART(dd, @d)) +
    dbo.TimeToTicks(DATEPART(hh, @d), DATEPART(mi, @d), DATEPART(ss, @d)) +
    (CONVERT(bigint, DATEPART(ms, @d)) * CONVERT(bigint,10000));
END

GO
```

Comment: I believe only DateToTicks fucntion is needed so you canr emove others

Comment: I have posted Eron Wright's code verbatim was it wasn't mine, and has stood the test of time (since 2003!). I also note he would be using the DateTimeToTicks function, and that depends on the others.

Answer (score 24):

I debated whether to post this because it depends on how dates are stored at the binary level in SQL Server, and so it is a very brittle solution.  For anything other than a one-off conversion, I would use something like the answer that @Solution Evangelist posted.  Still, you might find this interesting in an academic sort of way, so I'll post it anyway.

Making use of the fact that the accuracy of `DateTime2` matches up with the tick duration in .NET and that both are based on starting dates of `01-01-0001 00:00:00.0000000`, you can cast the `DateTime` to `DateTime2`, and then cast it to `binary(9)`: `0x07F06C999F3CB7340B`

The datetime information is stored RTL, so reversing, we'll get `0x0B34B73C9F996CF007`.

The first three bytes store the number of days since `01-01-0001` and the next 5 bytes store the 100ns ticks since midnight of that day, so we can take the number of days, multiply by the ticks in a day and add the ticks representing the time elapsed for the day.

Executing the following code:

```
set @date = getdate()
set @ticksPerDay = 864000000000

declare @date2 datetime2 = @date

declare @dateBinary binary(9) = cast(reverse(cast(@date2 as binary(9))) as binary(9))
declare @days bigint = cast(substring(@dateBinary, 1, 3) as bigint)
declare @time bigint = cast(substring(@dateBinary, 4, 5) as bigint)

select @date as [DateTime], @date2 as [DateTime2], @days * @ticksPerDay + @time as [Ticks]
```

returns the following results:

```
DateTime                DateTime2              Ticks
----------------------- ---------------------- --------------------
2011-09-12 07:20:32.587 2011-09-12 07:20:32.58 634514088325870000
```

Taking the returned number of Ticks and converting back to a DateTime in .NET:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(634514088325870000);
dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff").Dump();
```

Gets us back the date from sql server:

`2011-09-12 07:20:32.5870000`

Comment: Tx for your detailed post. For one-off conversion its a great solution but it is not my case.

Answer (score 5):

I was missing a millisec-accurate one-liner solution to this question, so here is one:

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST(CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS FLOAT)*8.64e8 AS BIGINT),-1)*1000+599266080000000000
```

8.64e8 = TimeSpan.TicksPerDay / 1000
599266080000000000 = DateTime.Parse('1900-01-01').Ticks

This works for the DATETIME type but not for DATETIME2. The 4/3 ms resolution of DATETIME makes it necessary to involve ROUND(…,-1): after the multiplication by 8.64e8 the float result always ends with either 0 or 33.3 or 66.6. This gets rounded to 0, 30 or 70.

Comment: So I see that `DATETIME2` crashes because `Explicit conversion from data type datetime2 to float is not allowed,` but admit that I don't understand why, precisely. [gbn does, however, provide a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52421814/1028230) by adding one more `CAST`, this time to `DATETIME`: `SELECT ROUND(CAST(CAST(CAST(SYSUTCDATETIME() as DATETIME) AS FLOAT)*8.64e8 AS BIGINT),-1)*1000+599266080000000000`

Comment: Works like a charm also for computing "(TimeSpan = DateTimeB-DateTimeA).Ticks" and converting it to BIGINT as 1 time data migration for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can use below sql to convert a date or utcdate to ticks

```
declare @date datetime2 = GETUTCDATE() or getdate()
declare @dateBinary binary(9) = cast(reverse(cast(@date as binary(9))) as binary(9))
declare @days bigint = cast(substring(@dateBinary, 1, 3) as bigint)
declare @time bigint = cast(substring(@dateBinary, 4, 5) as bigint)

select @date as [DateTime],  @days * 864000000000 + @time as [Ticks]
```

and use below sql to convert the tick to a date

```
SELECT Converted = CAST(635324318540000000/864000000000.0 - 693595.0 AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 3):

Tsk,

Here's the #1 recommendation simplified although I can't believe that was the top result. Surely this is built in, but at this point whatever I'm on a deadline. Refactoring took less than 1 min but maybe it'll help others who are looking for 1 stop solution.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Ticks] (@dt DATETIME)
RETURNS BIGINT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @year INT = DATEPART(yyyy, @dt)
DECLARE @month INT = DATEPART(mm, @dt)
DECLARE @day INT = DATEPART(dd, @dt)
DECLARE @hour INT = DATEPART(hh, @dt)
DECLARE @min INT = DATEPART(mi, @dt)
DECLARE @sec INT = DATEPART(ss, @dt)

DECLARE @days INT =
    CASE @month - 1
        WHEN 0 THEN 0
        WHEN 1 THEN 31
        WHEN 2 THEN 59
        WHEN 3 THEN 90
        WHEN 4 THEN 120
        WHEN 5 THEN 151
        WHEN 6 THEN 181
        WHEN 7 THEN 212
        WHEN 8 THEN 243
        WHEN 9 THEN 273
        WHEN 10 THEN 304
        WHEN 11 THEN 334
        WHEN 12 THEN 365
    END
    IF  @year % 4 = 0 AND (@year % 100  != 0 OR (@year % 100 = 0 AND @year % 400 = 0)) AND @month > 2 BEGIN
        SET @days = @days + 1
    END
RETURN CONVERT(bigint, 
    ((((((((@year - 1) * 365) + ((@year - 1) / 4)) - ((@year - 1) / 100)) + ((@year - 1) / 400)) + @days) + @day) - 1) * 864000000000) +
    ((((@hour * 3600) + CONVERT(bigint, @min) * 60) + CONVERT(bigint, @sec)) * 10000000) + (CONVERT(bigint, DATEPART(ms, @dt)) * CONVERT(bigint,10000));

END
GO
```

Comment: Atleast someone care for refactoring :) +1

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Updated due to updated details regarding original question

To give such precision of 100ns you should execute algorithm on SQL Server 2008 using new date type - [datetime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) which accuracy is 100 nanoseconds. Obviously link to an algorithm itself already provided in an other post.

[DateTime.Ticks Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth
>   of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.
>
> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond
>   intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001,
>   which represents DateTime.MinValue. It does not include the number of
>   ticks that are attributable to leap seconds.

```cs
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
System.Int64 ticks = dateTime.Ticks;
```

Answer (score 1):

A more performant solution might be: (note first two line are just for testing)

```
DECLARE @YourDate DATETIME

SET @YourDate = GETDATE()

SELECT 
(
  (
  -- seconds since 1970
  CAST(DATEDIFF(s,'1970-01-01 12:00:00',@YourDate) As BIGINT)
  )
-- seconds from 0001 to 1970 (approximate)
+ 62125920000
) 
-- make those seconds nanoseconds
* 1000000000
```

Given that your input date only goes down to seconds we just work it out in seconds and multiply by 1000000000 to get nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the unix time:

```
alter FUNCTION [dbo].[GETTICKS] (@datetime datetime)
RETURNS bigint
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN 
    RETURN 
        DATEPART(millisecond,@datetime) +
        CONVERT(bigint, 
                    1000 * (
                        DATEPART(second,@datetime) +
                        60 * DATEPART(minute,@datetime) +
                        3600 * DATEPART(hour,@datetime) +
                        3600 * 24 * DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,@datetime) +
                        convert(bigint, 3600 * 24 * (((DATEPART(year,@datetime) - 1970) * 365) + ((DATEPART(year,@datetime) - 1972) / 4)))
                ) )
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION UtcToTicks( @d datetime) RETURNS bigint
   AS
   BEGIN
       declare @d1 datetime
       set @d1 = convert(datetime,0)
       declare @days bigint = DATEDIFF(d,@d1,@d)
       declare @time bigint = DATEDIFF(ms,convert(datetime,@days),@d)
       return 599266080000000000 + 864000000000 * @days + @time * 10000
   END
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We can split it up into finding the minutes since 00:00:00 on January 1st 0001 and the microseconds portion of the time. We combine them to get the number of 100 nanoseconds since 00:00:00 on January 1st 0001. This looks like"

```
600000000*convert(bigint,(datediff(minute, '0001-01-01T00:00:00', datetime)+2880))+datepart(microsecond,datetime)*10
```