# How to cast sql datetime2 to double?

Tags: sql-server, data-conversion

I have a table in SQL Server 2016 with a column named "Start" of type datetime2(0).  In my application that pulls data from that table, I need to convert that columnar data to a double (I'm using a third party app that requires the data to be a double array).  I've tried to convert the data to a string in this way to pass it to my application:

```
SELECT Cast(Start AS CHAR(19)) FROM MyTable
```

and then converting that string in my application to a double.  This approach does not work because I cannot convert the string to a double.  What is a good approach to this?

Answer (score 3):

By double I assume you mean floating point.

datetime2(0) can be cast to datetime first (without loss of precision), which casts to float easily
Assuming you don't have values before 1753

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(Start AS datetime) AS float) FROM MyTable
```

Example

```
DECLARE @foo datetime2(0) = GETDATE()
SELECT @foo, CAST(CAST(@foo AS datetime) AS float)

-- 2018-09-20 11:31:32   43361.4802314815
GO

DECLARE @foo datetime2(0) = GETDATE()
SELECT @foo, CAST(@foo AS float) --error

--Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
--Explicit conversion from data type datetime2 to float is not allowed.
```

Answer (score 0):

If by chance you do need to work with dates before 1753, you can use DateDiff_Big to count the seconds from a fixed point in time, and divide by the number of seconds in a day.

DateDiff_Big is only available since SQL Server 2016. If you have an earlier version, you can do something similar with DateDiff, but it's slightly more complicated.

```
declare @x datetime2(0)

set @x = '2018-09-20T22:44:07'

select @x, 
       cast ( cast ( @x as datetime ) as float ),
       datediff_big(second,'0001-01-01T00:00:00.000', @x ) / cast(86400 as float) - 693595,
       (   datediff ( day, '0001-01-01T00:00:00.000', @x ) + datediff ( second, '00:00:00.000', cast(@x as time) ) / cast(86400 as float) ) - 693595

set @x = '1804-09-20T08:35:00'

select @x, 
       cast ( cast ( @x as datetime ) as float ),
       datediff_big(second,'0001-01-01T00:00:00.000', @x ) / cast(86400 as float) - 693595,
       (   datediff ( day, '0001-01-01T00:00:00.000', @x ) + datediff ( second, '00:00:00.000', cast(@x as time) ) / cast(86400 as float) ) - 693595

set @x = '1066-09-20T08:35:00'

select @x, 
--       cast ( cast ( @x as datetime ) as float ), -- won't work, before 1753.
       datediff_big(second,'0001-01-01T00:00:00.000', @x ) / cast(86400 as float) - 693595,
       (   datediff ( day, '0001-01-01T00:00:00.000', @x ) + datediff ( second, '00:00:00.000', cast(@x as time) ) / cast(86400 as float) ) - 693595
```