# Select SQL Server DatetimeOffset as .Net DateTimeOffset.Ticks

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, serialization

I send a SQL query and receive FOR JSON .

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(@"select top (1000) Date,[open],high,low,[close] from dbo.[foo"] where date > @backDate and date <= @Date  order by date FOR JSON AUTO", conn);

comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", _definition.dateFrom);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@backDate", lowLimit);

string json = (string)comm.ExecuteScalar();

Debug.WriteLine(json);

/* this causes invalid deserialization */
CudaEngine.OHLC[] stream = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CudaEngine.OHLC[]>(json);
```

So the `DateTimeOffset` in json result looks like this:

> [{"Date":"2019-07-30T00:29:00Z","open":1.241829000000000e+004,"high":1.245195000000000e+004,

My ohcl struct have to be like this with date as long.

```
public struct OHLC
{
    public long UTCdate;
    public double open;
    public double High;
    public double Low;
    public double Close;
}
```

How can I cast date directly from SQL statement to receive a .Net long either ticks   or millisecond? How can I deserialize without the `invalidCastException`?

Comment: are you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7386634

Comment: it will prolly hurt performance since its million rows i'm better store directly C# datetime as long ticks in database?

Comment: i find it strange i can't call a long from sql server even if its java long i can post process in GPU over having  the sql server calculate all this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
    public struct OHLC
    {
        private long _UTCdate { get; set; }

        public DateTime UTCdate
        {
            get { return DateTime.FromBinary(_UTCdate); }
            set { _UTCdate = value.ToBinary(); }
        }
        public double open { get; set; }
        public double High { get; set; }
        public double Low { get; set; }
        public double Close { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to convert in the SQL query.  The only tricky part (as always) is dealing with time zones.

If the SQL Server data type is `datetimeoffset` then you need to translate it to UTC time, then convert it to a `datetime2`, like this:

```
cast( [Date] at time zone 'UTC' as datetime2 )
```

If the SQL Server data type is a `datetime` or `datetime2` and already represents UTC time then you don't need this conversion.  And if they are `datetime` or `datetime2` stored in some local time zone, you need to convert to a `datetimeoffset` in with the appropriate time zone, then translate to UTC as above.  EG

```
cast( [Date] at time zone 'Central Standard Time' at time zone 'UTC' as datetime2 )
```

So assuming the SQL column is a `datetimeoffset` and you are converting to Unix Epoch Time, the query would look like:

```
var sql = @"
select top (1000) 
  datediff(second, '19700101', cast( [Date] at time zone 'UTC' as datetime2 ) ) Date,
  [open],
  high,
  low,
  [close] 
  from dbo.[foo"] 
  where date > @backDate 
  and date <= @Date  
  order by date 
  FOR JSON AUTO";

SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
```